# How can I plot this graph in R? I don't know the name of the graph. I just want to plot three variable in a single graph

Tags: r

[image: # [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9y6Nf.png)]

I'm doing my thesis in pulp and paper and I found this graph from an article to be very helpful in presenting data. But I don't know how to plot this kind of graph. Can anyone help me with this?

As I don't know the graph name, I was unable to try this.

Comment: No, this is a very bad graph and not helpful at all. This kind of graph is only useful if it is interactive and you can rotate it. I strongly recommend plotting the data as a heatmap or contour plot instead.

Comment: Thank you Roland for your valuable suggestion. I actually want to show relationship among three variables in a graph. And that graph was able to represent that relationship. Is there any other way to do that?

Comment: Yes, there are. I name some in my previous comment.

Comment: Thank you again. It is understandable to me now. I'll definitely try contour plot.

Answer (score 0):

first install `plot3D` in R and use the library. then you can use the following code:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- 1:10
m <- mesh(x, y)

#for example z = sin(x) + y
z <- sin(m$x) + m$y

surf3D(m$x, m$y, z, colvar = z, colkey = TRUE, 
       box = TRUE, bty = "b", phi = 10, theta = 30)
```